# Check if a resque job with specific args is pending in queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, resque

For example I enqueued a job as so

```ruby
Resque.enqueue(MyJob, user.id)
```

Before en-queueing another job with the same `user.id` I would like to check if there already exists a job with that user id in the queue.

I hope there is some syntax like:

```ruby
Resque.queue('MyQueue').has_pending_job(MyJob, user.id)
```

Comment: would love an answer to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's such thing, you can achieve the same with multiple options

1. You can have the `has_pending_jobs` attribute in the user, update it to true when the job starts and false when it ends
2. use the `resque-status` extension https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status to keep track of the `job_ids` that are en queued for a certain user
3. use separate queue for each user (this isn't scalable) and check if there's something in the queue for the user or not